# display in the content of info window in Google Map values retrieved from the MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

i am using PHP & MYSQL on wordpress in order to retrieve data from the database that contains coordinates and display markers on the Google Map.

Markers are shown on the map with the info window contains the coordinates.

i want to retrieve more info from the database and includes it in the info window

[image: infow windows]

in the debug mode it show the info that is i want to add to the info window  when i uncomment it markers will not show.

### code:

```
 <?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP2
        */

        get_header();
  ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=********&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 600px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

     var map,currentPopup;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };




        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
// i need to add here the info 
            //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });

          var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: feature.position.toString(),
     //or here   the info             
                    maxWidth: 300
                });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
        }



        var features = [
        <?php
          global $wpdb;
            $prependStr ="";
            foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT siteID, latitude, longitude FROM site_coordinates2", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
               $latitude = $row->latitude;
               $longitude = $row->longitude;
               $info = $row->siteID;
           echo $prependStr;
       ?>
{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
   // info:<?php echo $info;?>,

}
<?php
$prependStr =",";
}
?>
        ];



        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {

          addMarker(feature);
        }
}



         </script>


  </body>
</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

[image]

where the AM001 is the first Site ID in the MYSQL databases

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want us sietID as info

```
            var features = [
          <?php
            global $wpdb;
              $prependStr ="";
              foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT siteID, latitude, longitude FROM site_coordinates2", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
                 $latitude = $row->latitude;
                 $longitude = $row->longitude;
                 $info = $row->siteID;
             echo $prependStr;
         ?>
  {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
      info:<?php echo $info;?>,

  }
  <?php
  $prependStr =",";
  }
  ?>
          ];
```

then in your var popup you should add the info text

```
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: feature.position.toString() + ' my info siteID: ' + feature.info ,
              //or here   the info             
                maxWidth: 300
            });
```

Comment: i tied your answer it did not work markers are disappear

Comment: i will edit my answer and includes the error displayed in the console